# Hide Menu item in a Fragment on button click Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, visibility, menuitem

I have a fragment where I am displaying a Menu with 2 menu items. Currently the menu items are shown as the fragment is displayed. Now, I want to hide them once a certain action takes place eg. User deletes some text. I have tried the following code but the menu items still display :

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_details, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
            if (isDeleted)
            {
                status = false;
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit).setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I hide and unhide the menu items inside a fragment?

Comment: `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called once by default if you have other logic to rearrange menu then call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` after your desired work done

Answer (score 0):

What you've got now seems good, you're just missing [invalidateOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) call:

```
isDeleted = true;
getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do call invalidateOptionsMenu. but it still does not hide the already showing icons

Comment: Can you post your code where `invalidateOptionsMenu` being called?